# Embed value of variable to form new variable

Tags: php

I have a variable `$var` that can only be set to, let's say, `a` or `b`. I have two global arrays, e.g. `$aNames` and `$bNames`. Finally there's also a variable `$number`. To bring everything together, I'd like to combine the values to get an element from the array.

Example:

```
$var = 'a';
$number = 2;
$el = "$$var"."Names[".$number."]";

$el == $aNames[2] // true
```

But I'm not sure how to write that first `$el` line without it being interpreted as a string.

Comment: You may not take the warning, but this is not the proper way to do whatever you're trying to do.  Maybe use a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I appreciate the comment; I'm here to learn. Each page has some variables (in my post e.g. `$var` and `$number`), and based on that I want echo the URL to the previous page (same `$var`, but `$number-1`). As a solution I didn't find a better solution then to but the pages in an array e.g. `$aNames  = array('step-1.php', 'step-2.php', 'step-3.php');` and thus, get the correct filename. Is there a better way?

Comment: OK, you have a good answer for this particular prob.  If you ask a new question with details there is a better way at least better than variable variables `$$var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do:

```
$el = ${$var.'Names'}[$number];
```

Example:

```
<?php
$aNames[2] = 10;
$var = 'a';
$number = 2;
$el = ${$var.'Names'}[$number];
echo $el; //10
```

and now

```
$el == $aNames[2]
```

will evaluate to true